# Command to reboot and load Windows partition

Tags: windows, dual-boot, reboot

I have a Kali Linux and Windows 10 dual partition on my laptop. I'd like an easier way to load Windows from my Linux partition. By default Linux gets loaded first so I can't just reboot. Are there arguments I can give to the reboot command so that it will load Windows instead? I'd like to make an alias or script that can do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you want is `grub-reboot`, which sets the default boot entry in GRUB (for the next reboot only). Here's an example I use:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/grub-reboot "Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)"
```

I could have also used `sudo /usr/sbin/grub-reboot 2` (for the 3rd GRUB entry, as it starts with 0).

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for!